# Prove that can not write $U_1$, $U_2$ as $U_1 \oplus U_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the space of upper triangular $3\times3$ matrices.

$U_1=$ subspace of $V$ that every matrix in it and not equal to zero is Invertible

$U_2=$ subspace of $V$ all the matrices that not Invertible

($U_1$ not contain all the Invertible matrices )

> Prove that can not write $U1 , U2$ as $U1 \oplus U2$

to start I wrote $U2$ as :

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&a&b\\ 0&0&c\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

and $U1$ :

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}  \cup \begin{pmatrix}x&w&j\\ 0&y&l\\ 0&0&z\end{pmatrix}, x\ne 0 , y \ne 0, z\ne 0$$
I can see that $U1\cap U2 = {\{0}\}$

and I stuck here I dont know if what i wrote is correct and how to continue from here ..

any help how to continue ?

thx alot

Comment: U1 is not a subspace, right?

Comment: Whe you say “triangular”, do you mean “upper triangular?”

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos . my bad.. yes i mean upper triangular   i"ll fix it

Comment: @Quimey the question gives $U1$ as subspace

Comment: Your start with $U_2$ is wrong. Consider the diagonal matrix with diagonal $(0,0,1)$, for example.

Comment: @luqe Both the identity matrix and$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$belong to $U_1$, but their sum doesn't. Therefore, $U_1$ is not a subspace.

Comment: @luqe In my opinion, the problem makes no sense, because it asserts that two subsets of $V$ are subspaces when, in fact, none of them is.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  but the question says that $U1$ not subspace of all  all the Invertible matrices so it can be that $\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\notin U1$ plus in the question it give that $U1$ is subspace so this could be not true .

Comment: You have written this as though you were defining $U_1$ and $U_2$. I think you mean to say this: " $U_1$ and $U_2$ are subspaces of $V$. Every non-zero member of $U_1$ is invertible. Every member of $U_2$ is non-invertible. Prove that we cannot have $V=U_1 \oplus U_2$ ". If I am right you should amend the question.

Comment: If the OP meant the subspaces generated by those matrices then both are the whole space. For example all the "cannonical" basis vectors $e_{ij}$ are in $U2$.